# Django rest framework, set the api response Content-Encoding to gzip

Tags: python, json, django, http, django-rest-framework

Am working on django project, that act as a distribution server to other server when they request for some certain data through and api call, this data is in form of JSON and is very large. So i was thinking is there any way i can set my DRF APIView response to serves the outputted JSON response with gzip set for the Content-Encoding so as to reduce the size of the content, when consuming by the other servers.

Currently my application is running on gunicorn with nginx  on the front as a proxy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Django has a built-in [gzip middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.gzip).

If you're using django version <= 1.10 , in your `settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

If you're using django version > 1.10:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

This middleware should be placed before any other middleware that need to read or write the response body so that compression happens afterward.

Why? 
Because for an incoming request django processes the request using middlewares from top to bottom as defined in your settings.
For out going response middlewares are called bottom to top.

So declaring `gzip` middleware as the first middleware will enable the incoming request to be decompressed to be read by other middlewares ; and the outgoing response will be compressed just before leaving, so that it does not interfere with the operations of other middlewares.

Comment: Well explained let me give it a try, but it seem to make sense from your explanation.

Comment: @xssChauhan It's work for me. Is there any other way, may be some header settings at apache level for gzip?

Comment: @VaibhavKumar You can use `mod_deflate` to encode response. If it works, upvote the answer :)

Comment: ya, its work by adding `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json` in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.conf`. but don't know if there is any cons by using this.

Comment: @VaibhavKumar It is the better way. Much faster compared to python's gzip compression/decompression.