# unable to Send compressed gzip data using Django Rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, gzip

I am sending JSON file in Django Rest APIView framework.
I want to reduce the size of the file.
Implemented below code but Receving below error:

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def myMethod(request):

   from rest_framework.response import Response

   if request.method == 'POST':
       import gzip
       # ****Some code lines here to generated small json***
       myJson = json.dumps(parsed, indent=4)
       compressedContent = gzip.compress(myJson.encode('utf-8'), 5)  # compressedContent is byte format
       return Response(compressedContent, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

As mentioned in this link, I implemented middleware too.
[Django rest framework, set the api response Content-Encoding to gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589053/django-rest-framework-set-the-api-response-content-encoding-to-gzip)

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
...
]

Trying to call from Postman and it is showing below error.

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte.
500, Internal server error.**

Is there a way I can setup Accept-Encoding somewhere. I cannot figureout this.
Please note postman has Accept-Encoding to **gzip, deflate, br**

Could you please answer what is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I was having the same issue.

It is easier than expected. Just call the middleware in `settings.py` as the first in the list ([as explained in your link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589053/django-rest-framework-set-the-api-response-content-encoding-to-gzip)):

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware', #This one does the job
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

After that the middleware will handle the request compression. So there is no need to compress it in the code neither to declare new headers:

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def myMethod(request):

   from rest_framework.response import Response

   if request.method == 'POST':
       myJson = json.dumps(parsed, indent=4)
       return Response(myJson , status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Just be sure to have `Accept-Encoding: gzip` in your request.