# How to handle POST request with gzipped body using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, http, django-rest-framework, gzip

Here is the context :

- I have a web application with a backend API (coded with Django Rest Framework) besides Nginx as a reverse proxy, and a frontend.
- The user can POST data with some JSON content in the request body
- Everything works fine but I now want to compress the JSON content
- the body is gzipped on the front side (using Pako), and I want to handle this data on DRF side

The problem is DRF view (I'm using `ListCreateAPIView`) is expecting JSON data, so I can't call `request.data` to apply zlib decompression for example. I get a Malformed request (400 Bad request) due to compressed data : `JSON parse error - 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte`

Question is : how can I achieve this feature ?

From what I have found so far, Django Gzip middleware (see. [unable to Send compressed gzip data using Django Rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68649855/unable-to-send-compressed-gzip-data-using-django-rest-framework)) only provides compression, not decompression.
I also read that compression can lead to security risks.
Also, Nginx decompression documentation is only for responses, not requests.

I am a bit confused as compressing data to send over HTTP requests does not seem that foolish to me (or is it ?) and I don't find much resources on how to achieve this.
So maybe I'm missing something important here ?

Compression on the client side :

```js
async postData(json_data) {
    let headers = authHeader();
    headers['Content-Encoding'] = 'gzip';
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

    const data = json_data;
    const gz_data = pako.gzip(JSON.stringify(data));
    
    return axios
      .post(API_URL + 'create/', 
        data,
        {
          headers: headers,
        }
      )
      .then(response => {
        return response.data;
      })
  }
```

On Django view side:

```py
class DataList(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Filter transects based on user identity (token based)
        queryset = Data.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return queryset
    
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        transect_data = request.data # Returns 400 Bad request due to malformed expected JSON because it is gzipped
```